# How to display updated data repeatedly but want the screen to be cleared each time it updates

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, setinterval

I would like to update the status every 5 secs but i want the screen to be cleared each time it updates, i've tried including clearInterval (this.postStatus,5000) below the setInterval function but it still doesn't work.

```
const importdata = new Vue ({
    el: '#importdata',
    data(){
        return{
            status:[]
        }
    },
    methods: {
         getStatus() {
            fetch('https://a13.sglms.com.my/sglms/api/ios/19/')
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => this.status.push(data))
         }      
    },mounted (){ 

        setInterval(this.getStatus,5000),
        clearInterval(this.getStatus,5000)
    }
})
```

Comment: clearing the interval as soon as you set the interval would mean `this.getStatus` would never run - what do you think `clearInterval` does? how is that related to "clearing the screen" - other than both things have the word "clear" in them?

Comment: by the way, clearInterval takes a single argument, which is a value returned from `setInterval` - it does not work like addEventListener/removeEventListener - which you seem to think is the case

Comment: perhaps you want `this.status = data` instead of `this.status.push(data)`

Comment: I am not able to display my data using `this.status=data` on the webpage, that's why I use `this.status.push(data)` instead. @JaromandaX

Comment: so, you want to have ever increasing status - if not, clear the array before pushing to it

Comment: thanks, I'll figure that out @JaromandaX